# Are my piano keys defect (Yamaha YDP143)?

Tags: piano, digital-piano

I hope it is the right place to ask. I am a beginner to piano and I have a Yamaha YDP143 Digital Piano for practicing.

I have noticed that, there are strange noises with some keys (not Piano sound, but the key sound), and I am not sure if I shall contact seller for repair/replacement?

The problem (clicking noise) only occurs with middle C and D keys (C3 and D3), that I often encounter and it is quite irritating to have such an issue.
Could you please let me know if it sound OK, or is it something common that can occur and needs to be repaired?
Here I have added a video for it (Piano on, Volume down to zero)

[YouTube Video of Clicking Keys on Piano](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZvauCQQ1fs)

Thank you all for your help and support!

Comment: Contacting seller is no. 1. Also check Yamaha forums. Why haven't you?

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that I am not being extra suspicious and wanted to have the opinion of the some experienced users, as I am being a beginner as mentioned. Thanks for the info, though.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a reason for repair/replacement. It is only a matter of time until the key won't work any longer. Plus, the sound is annoying enough to disturb your musical pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, C and D are "looser" than the other keys.  Just normal wear-and-tear on heavily-used notes I think.  On a real piano there are adjustments.  Not so much on an electric keyboard I'm afraid.